# Oracle query issue in implementing logic for checking on million records

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table A

```
 code_Value   key_value  Description
  12          12         Entry_Category5
  13          rrtt         Entry2
  20          tht          Entry6
  20          trt          Wntry9
```

Table A has similar ways million records..

A logic is implemented in Table B which uses Table A as source

```
Code_value   Key_value       Description
    12          12            Entry_Category5

    13          rrtt          Entry2
    13          13            Null value

    20          tht            Entry6
    20          trt            Entry9
    20          20             Null value
```

The logic is, in table A if i have an entry, where code is not equal to key then a new entry of my previous code will be copied with key as the code,description must be null.
This logic must be applied to million records.I just want to have an sql query which will 
help me.Please suggest since there are more records

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
insert into table_b
select
    code_value,key_value,description
from
    table_a
where 
    code_value = key_value
union
select
    code_value,code_value,null
from 
    table_a
where 
    code_value != key_value
```